# Two lines of code that are saying the same thing?

Tags: objective-c, frame, cgrect, repeat

I am folowing this exercise in a book, and at one point, there is an implementation for a method that creates labels placed at random in the view. Here is the code:

```
 1   - (void)drawHypnoticMessage:(NSString *)message{
 2       for(int i =0; i<20; i++){
 3           UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

 4           messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 5           messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 6           messageLabel.text = message;
 7           [messageLabel sizeToFit];

 8           int width = self.view.bounds.size.width - messageLabel.bounds.size.width;
 9           int randomX = arc4random() % width;
 10          int height = self.view.bounds.size.height - messageLabel.bounds.size.height;
 11          int randomY = arc4random() % height;

 12          CGRect frame = messageLabel.frame;
 13          frame.origin = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY);
 14          messageLabel.frame = frame;

 15         [self.view addSubview:messageLabel];
 16      }
 17  }
```

This works fine. My question is regarding the lines 12 and 14. When I was copying this exercise to Xcode from the book and I reached line 12, I instinctively changed it to:

```
12   CGRect frame;
```

This didn't work, and I don't understand why. To me, lines 12 and 14:

```
12   CGRect frame = messageLabel.frame;

14   messageLabel.frame = frame;
```

Are saying the same thing twice, surely. Can anyone please explain why it is not so?

Comment: I think what you have to understand is that = means assignment in this context. It does not represent equality (as it would in an IF statement in some languages). Therefore A=B does not mean the same as B=A here, and line 13 adjusts the internal value before re-assigning the frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C overloads C's struct member access operator (.) to also access properties of Objective-C objects.  The problem is that you can't mix the two in a single assignment statement because the compiler's parser gets confused.

`messageLabel` is an object that has a property called `frame`.  `frame` is a struct with two members: `origin` and `size`.

To get around this limitation, you need to use a temporary variable to hold the struct (e.g. `frame`), manipulate this copy (structs are copied on assignment), and then assign the new struct (`frame`) to the property, which updates the property's value.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the frame in line 13, i.e. changing the origin value. The book is showing you a common technique to change the frame, because you can't change point or size value by itself.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this. Are you saying that by changing the origin of the frame (in line 13) somehow the frame stops being = to messageLabel.frame??

Comment: Yes, you create a new 'frame' which is has the value of messageLabel's frame, then you change this new 'frame' and have your messageLabel display this change, you assign your messageLabel frame to this new frame. You can achieve the same with this line of code, "messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, messageLabel.frame.size.width, messageLabel.frame.size.height);"